# single-row subquery returns more than one error in execute statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

why I am getting the below error for this statement ?

```
DECLARE COL_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
COL_COUNT :=0;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO COL_COUNT FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'P_TEST' AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
IF COL_COUNT = 0 THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('CREATE or replace PROCEDURE P_TEST IS BEGIN  null;   END;');
END IF;
END;
/
```

I add the image so the error become more clearer
[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I posted as a image so you can understand the error more clearly , ill add my code also. as for my code I am creating a procedure , I am not doing a select so I can get several results

Comment: I don't think the code will provide this error.

Comment: The code executed successfully in my environment.

Comment: @hemalp108 what will provoke this error then ?

Comment: @JSapkota i did run it on another environment and it work .. what wrong in my environment what would be different ?

Comment: @JSapkota there is no code in my editor , I add the screenshot to show that this the only I am executing . I know this error is not appropriate but its happening while I am running the code. I am executing only this block of code

Comment: Check this [Link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01427_single_row_subquery_returns_more_than_one_row.htm) for more info about the error. Can you let us know where and how are you executing the code?

Comment: @hemalp108 I guess there is a trigger created on level of schema, when I am running this block it seems its declaring that trigger. do you think `user_dependecy` would catch that trigger ?

Comment: You can check it in ALL_TRIGGERS or DBA_TRIGGERS just like other triggers.

Answer (score 0):

There was a trigger declared on schema level

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOG_ACTIVITY AFTER DDL ON SCHEMA
```

when I removed it it worked